# android cannot get size of taken photo.. a bug?

Tags: android, file

In my app I have options to take/select photo, audio or video files. I write each file path in its own string and perform some actions with it. Also, I use it to determine the file size with following method:

```
    public double getSize(String path) {

    File file = new File(path);

    if (file.exists()) {
        long size = file.length();

        return size;
    } else {
        Log.e("zero size", "the file size is zero!");
        return 0;

    }

}
```

It works fine BUT the method always returns 0 while trying to get the size of a taken picture.

```
   double s = 1.0 * getSize(taken_pic_path) / 1024 / 1024;
```

taken_pic_path is 100% correct for 3 reasons: 1). I use the same path to create a preview and it works. 2). I let the path to be shown via a Toast and it seems to be correct 3). I check the path with file.exists() and it returns true. I also tried the following:

```
File file = new File(taken_pic_path);
if (file.exists()){
   double test = file.lenght();
}
```

I always get a zero as file size.. same technique works perfectly with taken video, taken audio, selected picture/video/audio, I'm only getting 0 while trying to get the size of a taken photo. Just can't get the reason.. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I made all possible checks:

```
 if (file.exists()) {

            String b = file.getPath();
            boolean r = file.canRead();
            boolean w = file.canWrite();
            double d = file.length();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Boolean.toString(r),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Boolean.toString(w),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(d),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

OUTPUT: correct file path / true / true / 0.0
what the hell......

Comment: is it 0 before you divide it ?

Comment: I was told to use double in a previous topic, otherwise I would get a zero when the result is less than one. I then use a method to round it to 2 decimals. Yep, it is already zero. getSize always returns 0 used with that path

Comment: less than one ? length is in bytes, a files less than 1 byte long seem unlikely ...

Comment: sure. Just took a picture:  /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1356018878923.jpg

Comment: When you step through, is getSize() returning zero because the file size is reported as zero or because file.exists() returns false?  Both paths will return zero.  BTW, no need for double.  file.length() returns a long int.

Comment: the keyword is Reported as zero. file.exists() returns true. But the size cannot be zero since my preview bitmap created from the same path is set correctly

Comment: Is it possible, that the producer did not yet close the file when you try to get its length?

Comment: actually the file isn't open. Thats my app logic: start camera for result - create bitmap from data returned by intent - convert it to byte array - get taken image Uri from intent - start next Activity passing it 2 extras: byte array and Uri. Next Activity: decode byte array and set bitmap as preview, get image Uri and convert it to real path - create a new file from the path - exists? - true - file.lenght - returns 0. I tried to call finish() on previous activity but it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

try

```
double s = 1.0 * (double) getSize(taken_pic_path) / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
```

Comment: same result. Tried 

File file = new File(taken_pic_path);
   
   if(file.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file is there!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     s = 1.0 * (double) getSize(taken_pic_path) / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(s), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

Result: file is there!  0.0

Comment: The documentation says: File.length(): The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. It looks like you haven't saved the image properly.

Comment: the image is saved automatically by the camera app. And if it wasn't, I would not be able to create a bitmap to use as preview from the same path, but it is not the case. Bitmap is created properly

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon the same issue. For some devices, when the Android Media Provider notifies about new content added to the provider, the file still reports length zero. It is only after half a second or so that the correct length is reported.

I would consider this a bug.

My work-around is so ugly as this:

```
/**
 * Careful: this method may take a few seconds to complete for some photos.
 * <p>
 * Do not attempt to read {@link Images.Media.SIZE}, since it is known to return
 * wrong results (up to 5% off). We used to use it until 2.2.0.
 * 
 * @return the file size, or zero if the file does not exist
 * @see #isFileReallyAvailable
 */
private static long getFileSize(File file) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (file.length() > 0) {
            return file.length();
        } else if (isFileReallyAvailable(file)) {
            return file.length();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "The file " + file.getName() + " was not available. Will report size 0");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Is this file really available to be read? That is, does it have a non-zero length?
 * <p>
 * Seems like
 * some photo-taking apps (even the standard one in some devices) notify the Media provider
 * too soon, so {@code file.getLength()} is still zero. In those cases, we will retry
 * a few times after some sleeps. Related story: #59448752
 * <p>
 * Careful: this method may take a few seconds to complete for some photos, so do not call
 * it from the GUI thread.
 * <p>
 * Also, do not attempt to read {@link Images.Media.SIZE}, since it is known to return
 * wrong results (up to 5% off). We used to use it until 2.2.0.
 * 
 * @return the file size, or zero if the file does not exist
 */
private static boolean isFileReallyAvailable(File file) {
    boolean available = false;
    final long timeout = 2000; // In the Nexus 4 I tried, 700 ms seems like the average
    final long sleepEveryRetry = 100;
    long sleepSoFar = 0;
    do {
        try { Thread.sleep(sleepEveryRetry); } catch (Exception e) {}
        final long fileSize = file.length();
        available = fileSize > 0;
        sleepSoFar += sleepEveryRetry;
        Log.v(TAG, "The file " + file.getName() + " is still not valid after " + sleepSoFar + " ms");
    } while (!available && sleepSoFar < timeout);

    return available;
}
```

These are the logs that this generate on the only phone I have where I can reproduce this (a Nexus 4 running 4.3):

```
10-30 18:17:03.324: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181702.jpg is still not valid after 100 ms
10-30 18:17:03.424: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181702.jpg is still not valid after 200 ms
10-30 18:17:03.524: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181702.jpg is still not valid after 300 ms
10-30 18:17:03.634: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181702.jpg is still not valid after 400 ms
10-30 18:17:03.734: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181702.jpg is still not valid after 500 ms
10-30 18:17:03.774: V/Scanner(21167): Found a new undiscovered image in the local phone: upload wrapper for IMG_20131030_181702.jpg (ID = <none>, 25 KB, JUST_DISCOVERED) (source item ID is 3126)

10-30 18:17:06.537: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181705.jpg is still not valid after 100 ms
10-30 18:17:06.637: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181705.jpg is still not valid after 200 ms
10-30 18:17:06.737: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181705.jpg is still not valid after 300 ms
10-30 18:17:06.837: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181705.jpg is still not valid after 400 ms
10-30 18:17:06.937: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181705.jpg is still not valid after 500 ms
10-30 18:17:07.038: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181705.jpg is still not valid after 600 ms
10-30 18:17:07.058: V/Scanner(21167): Found a new undiscovered image in the local phone: upload wrapper for IMG_20131030_181705.jpg (ID = <none>, 24 KB, JUST_DISCOVERED) (source item ID is 3127)

10-30 18:17:07.969: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181707.jpg is still not valid after 100 ms
10-30 18:17:08.069: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181707.jpg is still not valid after 200 ms
10-30 18:17:08.169: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181707.jpg is still not valid after 300 ms
10-30 18:17:08.289: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181707.jpg is still not valid after 400 ms
10-30 18:17:08.389: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181707.jpg is still not valid after 500 ms
10-30 18:17:08.499: V/Scanner(21167): The file IMG_20131030_181707.jpg is still not valid after 600 ms
10-30 18:17:08.509: V/Scanner(21167): Found a new undiscovered image in the local phone: upload wrapper for IMG_20131030_181707.jpg (ID = <none>, 20 KB, JUST_DISCOVERED) (source item ID is 3128)
```